# Section name not displaying correctly in ToC

Tags: table-of-contents, sections-paragraphs

I faced a problem with the Table Of Content in LaTeX (see the picture)[image: problem with the table of content in LaTeX]

The code I'm using:

Preambule:

```latex
\usepackage[left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancyplain}
\setlength{\headwidth}{\textwidth}
\setlength{\headsep}{0.5cm}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm,cases}
\usepackage{array,dcolumn,booktabs,multirow,makecell}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{dsfont}

\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{0.2cm}{}
```

Document:

```tex
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\setcounter{page}{1}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}% Remove header rule
\fancyhead[L]{\small{Rapport Projet Maths}}
\fancyhead[C]{Projet Maths}
\fancyhead[R]{\small{ENSISA -- Mulhouse (2021--2022)}}

\section*{Préambule}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Préambule}

\subsection*{Définition des termes utilisés}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Définition des termes utilisés}
[...]
\section{choix uniforme de l'un des $K$ traitements}
[...]
```

Also, I would like to know why there are no dots for section like there are for subsection.

Comment: First of your should provide a full but minimal exmaple that others can copy and test as is. Secondly, it is probably not a good idea to redefine `\thesection` like that. Perhaps you should explain what your end goal is here.

Comment: What is the `\no` does? Did you define it?

Comment: @Tom, the \no command is defined in `\usepackage[french]{babel}` which show `n°`

Comment: Could you provide a  minimal work example? include all the setting in your preamble and some basic content in the document

Comment: @daleif, Maybe I could share an Overleaf link with my preambule and my document.

I would like to create a ToC, but as you can see the second section isn't dispalaying correctly the text overlap

[Overleaf Link](https://fr.overleaf.com/read/jdnzrnbfbgbv)

Comment: @Tom, sure, here's the link to the Overleaf procject https://fr.overleaf.com/read/jdnzrnbfbgbv

Comment: No, please provide code here (update your question), links rot over time and thus your question will not be useful for others in the future

Comment: I found a way to fix my problem about the text overlaping using the package `tocloft`:

`\addtolength{\cftsecnumwidth}{2.45cm}`

About the dots line, I found this to make it appears fo section in ToC:

`\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}`

Comment: @daleif, alright, is it better now?

Comment: Not really, we cannot copy this and compile it without adding anything. For example there's no document class

Answer (score 1):

Use the `tocloft` package.

```
\documentclass...
\usepackage{tocloft}
```

Provide more space for the section number:

```
\renewcommand{\cftsecnumwidth}{4em} % change 4em to suit
```

Dotted leader for sections:

```
\renewcommand{\cftsecdotsep}{\cftdotsep}
```

Read the manual for more information.